# Master Detail View I would like to segue back to master view rather than detail view

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I have created a master-detail view and from the detail view I have created segues to various view controllers.
When I tap on one of the view controllers the user is returned to the detail view but I would like to return directly to the master view, where the table is shown.
I have looked at previous posts on this but either do not understand them or they do not work for me.
e.g. Someone wrote  writing "self.preferredDisplayMode = .AllVisible" but if that is an answer I cannot see where I would write the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided there is no satisfactory way to do this

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like what you are looking for is an Unwind Segue, where you set the master view controller as the destination from wherever the user is sitting in the view controller hierarchy.

[Here is a tutorial](http://ashishkakkad.com/2015/04/work-with-unwind-segue-in-swift-language-ios-8/) from another frequent [StackOverflow contributor](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3202193/ashish-kakkad) that might help you out.

Comment: Creating an unwind segue isn't trivial, but there are not too many steps.  Are you sure it's not working simply because you might have missed a step in setting it up?

Comment: I've used the code from the tutorial but it only takes me back to the detail view

Comment: According to the tutorial, *"you have to add this code in the view controller where you want to unwind (come back to)"*.  Did you add the code to the detail view instead of your master view controller?

Comment: I added it to the master view controller